# Prisma findMany function is not returning relational data

Tags: javascript, postgresql, prisma

I am trying to populate my data with relational data using Prisma 2.28.0, Here is my

Schema.prisma model below

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model Product {
  id           Int         @id @default(autoincrement())
  name         String         @db.VarChar(255)
  transactions Transaction[]
}

model Transaction {
  id        BigInt   @id @default(autoincrement())
  quantity  Int
  time      Int
  product  Product? @relation(fields: [productId], references: [id])
  productId Int?
}
```

the function I am trying to fetch data.

```
const { PrismaClient }=require("@prisma/client")

const prisma = new PrismaClient()

async function checkPrismaConnection(){
    try {
        const result=await prisma.product.findMany();
        console.log(result);
    }catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}

 checkPrismaConnection();
```

OutPut

```
[
  { id: 1, name: 'John Doe' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Masum' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Rezaul' }
]
```

Transaction DB result
[image]

Product DB

[image]

I don't know why my findMany() is not retuning relational db data. Thank you

Comment: The screenshot of your database result seems to be a result of transactions (that reference a product id), while your code seems to be querying just products. Copied the code/screenshot incorrectly or so?

Comment: I've attached product db screenshot now and updated my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest reading the documentation, especially [this chapter](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/relation-queries#include-all-fields-for-a-specific-relation) and the ones following that. In their example, they have an `Author` and `Post`, where `Post` has an `author` field pointing at an `Author`. Their code looks like this:

```js
const getPosts = await prisma.post.findMany({
  where: {
    title: {
      contains: 'cookies',
    },
  },
  include: {
    author: true, // Return all fields
  },
})
```

The chapter "Include deeply nested relations" a bit lower actually uses a field `.category` that's also an array, as in your example with `.transactions`.

Comment: If I use it It pupulates relation db as an object, but other record who doesn't have any relation with others is not showing..

Comment: Not sure what exactly what you're problem is. Perhaps close this question and create a new one with your updated code and its updated (and expected) results.

Answer (score 2):

You need to explicitly set include to true.

So the code will look like this for you

```
const { PrismaClient }=require("@prisma/client")

const prisma = new PrismaClient()

async function checkPrismaConnection(){
   try {
    const result=await prisma.product.findMany({
      include: {
        transaction: true,
       },
   });
    console.log(result);
}catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
}

 checkPrismaConnection();
```